# How to compare two rows against a column in a sql table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's the Table:

```
Program        Year    Month       Action            Date
2006060_PR     2017      1         Approval         3/1/2017
2006060_PR     2017      2         Approval         4/1/2017
2006060_PR     2017      3         Approval         4/1/2017
2006060_PR     2017      4         Approval         4/1/2017
2006060_PR     2017      5         Approval         5/1/2017
```

Desired Result should be to track date changes against the Month column as below:

```
Month   EU_Date
1       3/1/2017
2       4/1/2017
5       5/1/2017
```

This query is not working. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
Select  distinct A.Month, A.Date
from Table A inner join
     Table B
      on A.Program = B.Program  
where A.Year = 2017 and A.Program = '2006060_PR' and
      A.Action = 'Approval' and A.Date <> B.Date and A.Month < B.Month
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want a simple aggregation:

```
Select A.Date, min(A.Month)
from Table A 
where A.Year = 2017 and A.Program = '2006060_PR' and
      A.Action = 'Approval'
group by A.Date;
```